# Closing window in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I just want to close a window in my application. please help
The code is

```html
 <div class="content">
<a class="icon-close cancel" href="">
<i class="icon eldorado_delete"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you, but I recommend to use ids for elements.

```
WebElement close = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'cancel')]"));
close.click();
```

Comment: Can you pls write it by the css method

Comment: By.cssSelector(".icon-close .cancel")

Answer (score 0):

Try this

By.cssSelector("a.icon-close.cancel")

Answer (score 0):

Simply use write:

```
   driver.close();
```

If you have more than two windows use below line to close all the windows except parent window:

```
   //to get Parent widnow
   String parentWidnow = driver.getWindowHandle();
   Set<String> childWidnows= driver.getWindowHandles();
   for (String childWidnow: childWidnows) {
      if (!str.contains(parentWindow)) {
          driver.close();
      }
   }
```